# Finding the coefficient of $x^{18}$ in $({5x^6 + 3x^{-3}})^9$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Doing some homework and we were given the question below,
[image: Question]

And a sample solution to a different question in roughly the same format:

[image: Sample solution]

I was just looking for some help in understanding the way to go about doing the question. My main issue is where did they determine that $x^2$ was equivalent to $x^{12}$. After that I should be good.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think about the binomial expansion, it consists of terms that are products of $x^6$ and $x^{-3}$  If you have $a$ terms of $x^6$ and $b$ terms of $x^{-3}$ you need $a+b=9, 6a-3b=18$. Solve those equations, then think about the binomial coefficient.

Comment: ok so solved we get a = 5 and b = 4, what do you mean about the binomial coefficient?

Comment: When you expand a power, there is a factor of the binomial coefficient, here $9 \choose 4$.  Basically it is the number of ways to choose the first factor $a$ times and the second factor $b$ times.

Comment: Gotcha, so the answer would be 126*3125*81 or 31893750?

Comment: Looks good to me. It would be good to show where the terms in $126*3125*81$ come from.  In this case it is easy to guess, but writing it as ${9 \choose 4}*5^5\cdot 3^{4}$would make it easier to validate.

Comment: Yes the is correct to how I got those terms, thanks for all the help, I greatly appreciate it, I would upvote, but new user and such!